# How to replace the user IDs and group IDs with names instead of numbers in "ps"?

Tags: linux, process, users

The following command will list the effective user ID and the effective group ID of each process:

```
ps -o pid,euid,egid
```

But the IDs will be listed as numbers, for example:

```
PID  EUID  EGID
123  1000  1000
421  1000  1000
```

Is there a way to list the IDs as names? For example:

```
PID  EUID  EGID
123  chris group_a
421  chris group_a
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run

```
ps -o pid,euser,egroup
```

instead